# Tweepy: Get Tweet's Expansions

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

*Hey there!* I made this basic code that will reply to every tweet mentioning my Twitter bot.

```py
# This is so the bot only looks for the most recent tweets.
start_id = 1
initialisation_resp = client.get_users_mentions(client_id)
if initialisation_resp.data is not None:
    start_id = initialisation_resp.data[0].id

# Looking for mentions tweets in an endless loop
while True:
    response = client.get_users_mentions(client_id, since_id=start_id)
    # Reply Code
    if response.data is not None:
        for tweet in response.data:
            try:
                client.create_tweet(in_reply_to_tweet_id=tweet.id, text=":)")
                start_id = tweet.id
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

    # Delay (so the bot doesn't search for new tweets a bunch of times each second)
    time.sleep(5)
```

***Question:*** How can I get a Tweet's object **expansions** (get more information about the tweet such as Tweets’ author, attached media, etc...) because the tweet object just offers those two options: tweet id and text?

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/expansions_and_fields.html)